# Keyboard layout setting in DOSBox has no effect

Tags: keyboard-layout, dosbox

DOSBox forces Czech keyboard on me for use in the console, which isn't even funny. I googled and found how [manual advises to change layout](http://www.dosbox.com/DOSBoxManual.html#KeyboardLayout):

> To switch to a different keyboard layout, either the entry `keyboardlayout` in the `[dos]` section of the DOSBox `dosbox.conf` configuration file can be used

So I edited my file, which now contains the following:

```
[dos]
keyboardlayout=us103
[autoexec] 
keyboardlayout=us103
MOUNT C C:\MYSELF\Hry\DOS
C:
```

This doesn't work. Keyboard remains Czech. I ran these commands to verify what keyboard is configured and that the command works. It does, see below:

[image: image description]

So the question: How to configure DOSBox layout to be permanently US?

**Note:** The available layouts appear to be these (copied here for future reader's reference):

```
us103 (us), ux103 (ux)                       US, US International
dv103 (dv), lh103 (lh), rh103 (rh)           US Dvorak, Left-Hand, Right-Hand
sq448, sq452 (sq)                            Albania
hy                                           Armenia*
az                                           Azerbaijan*
by463 (bl463,by,bl)                          Belarus*
be120 (be)                                   Belgium
ba234 (ba)                                   Bosnia & Herzegovina
br274, br275 (br)                            Brazil
bg241, bg442 (bg)                            Bulgaria
ca58 (cf58,ca,cf), ca445 (cf445), cf501      Canada
hr234 (hr)                                   Croatia
cz243, cz                                    Czech Republic
dk159 (dk)                                   Denmark
ee454 (et454,ee,et)                          Estonia*
fo                                           Faroe Islands
fi153 (su153,fi,su)                          Finland
fr120, fr189 (fr)                            France
ka                                           Georgia*
de129 (gr129,de,gr), de453 (gr453)           Germany
gk220 (el220), gk319 (el319,gk,el), gk459 (el459)  Greece
hu208, hu                                    Hungary
is458 (is), is161 (is197)                    Iceland
it141 (it), it142                            Italy
kk                                           Kazakhstan*
ky                                           Kyrgyzstan*
la171 (la)                                   Latin-American-Spanish
lv, lv455                                    Latvia*
lt210, lt211, lt212 (lt), lt221, lt456       Lithuania*
mk449 (mk)                                   Macedonia
mt47 (ml47), mt (ml)                         Malta
mn (mo)                                      Mongolia*
nl143 (nl)                                   Netherlands
no155 (no)                                   Norway
ph                                           Philippines
pl214, pl457 (pl)                            Poland
po163 (po)                                   Portugal
ro333 (ro), ro446                            Romania
ru441 (ru), ru443                            Russia
sr118 (sr), sr450                            Serbia & Montenegro
sk245 (sk)                                   Slovakia
si234 (si)                                   Slovenia
es172 (sp172,es173,sp173,es,sp)              Spain
sv153 (sv)                                   Sweden
sd150 (sg150,sd,sg), sf150 (sf)              Swiss
tm                                           Turkmenistan
tr179 (tr), tr440                            Turkey
ua465 (ur465), ua (ur)                       Ukraine*
uk166 (uk), uk168                            United Kingdom
uz                                           Uzbekistan*
yu234 (yu)                                   Yugoslavia
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to configure DOSBox layout to be permanently US?

> keyboardlayout=us103

Try

```
keyboardlayout=us
```

without the trailing `103`.

You can also use the `keyb` command:

```
keyb us
```

---

#### keyb

> Introduction
>
> Keyb is used to change the layout of the keyboard used for different
>   countries. Syntax
>
> Configures a keyboard for a specific language.
>
> ```
> KEYB [keyboard layout code/id]
> ```
>
> For example the following will set your keyboard layout to a Swedish
>   keyboard:
>
> ```
> KEYB sv
> ```
>
> or for not default character set:
>
> ```
> KEYB sv 437
> ```
>
> The keyboard layout can also be set in dosbox.conf (see
>   Configuration:DOS), so it can also be set with the internal CONFIG
>   command:
>
> ```
> CONFIG -set dos keyboardlayout [keyboard layout code/id]
> ```

Source [DOSBox Wiki - KEYB](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/KEYB)

Comment: Hah. Apparently the problem was that DOS Box ignored conf file. After resolving that issue, all above mentioned methods work.